# Blazor middleware to run after navigating to any page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, middleware

I have written a middleware class but currently only runs when I start the application, I want it to run every time the app navigates to a different page.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: SPA = "Single Page" application, from the servers perspective you only navigate to one page. Page navigation is internal to the SPA. Is this server-side or wasm?

Comment: It is blazor server.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event for this type of middleware as Blazor utilizes websockets to render the UI, not traditional HTTP requests which is what you were expecting. Example of `MainLayout.razor` or any component that will only rendered once:

```html
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavMgr

<h1>My Component</h1>
```

```cs
@code
{
    public OnInitialized()
    {
        // Bind the LocationChanged event
        NavMgr.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }
    private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
       // My code to execute when navigation has changed
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Always unbind the event on component disposal
        NavMgr.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;   
    }
}
```